# OpenAM Redirect issue

Tags: reverse-proxy, opensso

I am trying to setup an IdP Provider using OpenAM(OpenSSO) with a 3rd party SP.  I currently have OpenAM behind Apache reverse proxy with OpenAM configured to use an internal DNS.  When I access OpenAM through the proxy, OpenAM redirects to the internal DNS instead which cannot be resolved by the browser.

I've tried setting the com.sun.identity.server.fqdnMap[public.domain.com]=internal.domain.com property and even swapping the (in)valid values around.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  I needed to setup a site (Configuration > Servers and Sites) in OpenAM for the proxy server and added the proxy domain to the cookie list (Configuration > System > Platform) within OpenAM.